# radius search in solr to get results

Tags: solr

i have two db tables city and provider where.

1. city:id, name, Longitude, Latitude
2. provider:id,city_name,type,member_id

now i want to do a 300 km radius search say from city Ex: Bangalore to get cities with provider's count > 100(means provider.city_name = city.name).

i am doing facet search

```
solrQuery.setFacet(true);
        solrQuery.addFacetField('city');
        solrQuery.setQueryType("geo")
        solrQuery.setParam("lat", city.latitude.toString())
        solrQuery.setParam("long", city.longitude.toString())
        Double distanceInMiles = 500.0 * 0.621371192;
        solrQuery.setParam("radius", distanceInMiles.toString());
        def server = solrService.getServer('provider')
```

i will get all the cities and foreach(in java) city again i am running a check weather there are more than 100 provider's in that city or not. is there any better way to do this in solr????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.setFacetMinCount(100)` to only get facet values where the count is over 100. That would mean your facet values only contains cities where there are at least 100 providers.